# Python regex matching all but last occurrence

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, directory

So I have expression such as "./folder/thisisa.test/file.cxx.h" How do I substitute/remove all the "." but the last dot?

Comment: The one I put is faster. Well, you won't see the difference though.

Comment: it's probably faster to use a loop to replace them all, keep track of the index of the last replacement, and replace back to a dot the last one after the loop.

Comment: If you're manipulating pathnames, give a look at `os.path`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To match all but the last dot with a regex:

```
'\.(?=[^.]*\.)'
```

Using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check that's there another dot after the one we found (the lookahead's not part of the match).

Answer (score 2):

Without regular expressions, using [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) and [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
s = "./folder/thisisa.test/file.cxx.h" 
s.replace('.', '', s.count('.')-1)
# '/folder/thisisatest/filecxx.h'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Specific one-char solution**

In your *current scenario*, you may use

```
text = re.sub(r'\.(?![^.]*$)', '', text)
```

Here, `\.(?![^.]*$)` matches a `.` (with `\.`) that is not immediately followed (`(?!...)`) with any 0+ chars other than `.` (see `[^.]*`) up to the end of the string (`$`).

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kPt2Qe/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rVyCLf).

**Generic solution for 1+ chars**

In case you want to replace a `.` **and** any more chars you may use a capturing group around a character class with the chars you need to match and add the positive lookahead with `.*` and a backreference to the captured value.

Say, you need to remove the last occurrence of `[`, `]`, `^`, `\`, `/`, `-` or `.` you may use

```
([][^\\./-])(?=.*\1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/88gjH3/1).

**Details**

- `([][^\\./-])`  - a capturing group matching `]`, `[`, `^`, `\`, `.`, `/`, `-` (note the order of these chars is important: `-` must be at the end, `]` must be at the start, `^` should not be at the start and `\` must be escaped)
- `(?=.*\1)` - a positive lookahead that requires any 0+ chars as many as possible and then the value captured in Group 1.

[Python sample code](https://ideone.com/nmQ9yA):

```
import re
text = r"./[\folder]/this-is-a.test/fi^le.cxx.LAST[]^\/-.h"
text = re.sub(r'([][^\\./-])(?=.*\1)', '', text, flags=re.S)
print(text)
```

Mind the `r` prefix with string literals. Note that `flags=re.S` will make `.` match any linebreak sequences.

Comment: 2 clear solutions, I don't see anything wrong with his answer. +1