# How would I replace all but the last period with underscore?

Tags: r

How would I replace all but the last period with underscore?

```
x <- "foo.foo.foo.foo.f"
# "foo_foo_foo_foo.f"
```

Comment: thanks, @ZheyuanLi. that does work in this case, but i need a more flexible approach. actual use case is not always ".fo". maybe i've provided a bad example in this respect.

Comment: i've come across a few ideas, including [this `'\.(?=[^.]*\.)'` lookahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203365/python-regex-matching-all-but-last-occurance) for python, but i get an invalid regex error.

Comment: Just make that Python one R compatible `gsub("\\.(?=[^.]*\\.)", "_", x, perl = TRUE)`.

Comment: thanks, @RichardScriven. are there any reasons to avoid perl-like regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Richard Scriven's comment worked best for me:

```
gsub("\\.(?=[^.]*\\.)", "_", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is helpful

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_last(str = stri_replace_all(str = x,regex = "\\.",replacement = "\\_"),regex = "\\_",replacement = "\\.")
```

Answer (score 0):

A PCRE option would be

```
gsub("(\\.[^.]*)$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\.", "_", x, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "foo_foo_foo_foo.f"
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach, but should do what you need it to:

```
library(stringr)

x <- "foo.foo.foo.foo.f"

x_split <- str_split(x, "\\.")[[1]]

x_new <- paste(x_split[-length(x_split)], collapse = "_")
x_new <- paste(x_new, x_split[length(x_split)], sep = ".")

x_new
# "foo_foo_foo_foo.f"
```

It will always treat the last split differently and will generalise to any possible text between the periods.

You could probably avoid the use of the `stringr` package if you wanted to (it just wraps stringi and base R string functions with a common interface).