# Regex match repeating patterns but not last occurrence

Tags: regex

I would like to extract the following patterns:

1. Initial by letter (Subgroup 1); and then
2. followed by numbers of any length (Subgroup 2);
3. followed by letter or any length (Subgroup 3);
4. repeating 2 & 3 of any occurrences.

I am using https://regexr.com/ to test.

Here are some samples string and my expected output.

```
String: FAF46ABC7787AAAA  =>   Desired output: FAF46ABC7787

String: FAF46ABC7787      =>   Desired output: FAF46ABC

String: FAF46ABC          =>   Desired output: FAF46

String: FAF46             =>   Desired output: FAF

String: FAF               =>   Desired output: FAF

String: FAF46 GG(Not CC)  =>   Desired output: FAF

String: FAF46.doc         =>   Desired output: FAF
```

I tested the following but not working:

1. Lookahead method suggested by

[Python regex matching all but last occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203365/python-regex-matching-all-but-last-occurrence)

1a. `^([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*)(?=[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)`

1b. `^([a-zA-Z]+)(([0-9])*([a-zA-Z])*)(?=[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)`

2. Capture all subgroups and exclude last occurrence by loop

2a. `^([a-zA-Z]+)(([0-9]*)([a-zA-Z]*))*`

3. Using replace method

3a. `(^(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)*)([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)` and replace by $1

4. Exclude ending occurrence by using non-capturing group

4a. `^([a-zA-Z]+)(([0-9]*)([a-zA-Z]*))*(?:[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)$`

4b. `^([a-zA-Z]+)(([0-9]*)([a-zA-Z]*))*(?:([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+))$`

4c. `^([a-zA-Z]+)(([0-9]*)([a-zA-Z]*))*(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)$`

4d. `^([a-zA-Z]+)(([0-9]*?)([a-zA-Z]*?))*(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)$`

I also change greedy or lazy to see if any miracles happen. But no luck.

I thought it should be easy task. But it is obvious that it is harder than what I thought.

I would appreciate for any kind of help.

Please note that I do not have extended regex if it is the case to work it work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```bash
^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*?)(?:[0-9]+|[A-Z]*)\b.*
```

and replace with `$1`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rZ4Ki/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `[a-zA-Z]+`: Match 1+ letters
  - `[0-9a-zA-Z]*?`: Match 0 or more letter or digits (non-greedy)
- `)`: End 1st capture group
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[0-9]+`: Match 1+ digits
  - `|`: OR
  - `[A-Z]*`: Match 0 or more uppercase letters
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `.*`: Match anything remaining